# Mongodb Kafka Connector how to watch multiple collections

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka-connect, mongodb-kafka-connector

I'm trying to capture MongoDb change data using Mongo Kafka Connector. It works when I put a collection name i.e. `collection=collection1` with `pipeline` as `[{"$match":{"operationType":{"$in":["insert","update","replace","delete"]}}}]` but I'm unable to get it to work when I leave collection empty and I use the following `pipeline=[{"$match": {"ns.coll": {"$regex": /^(collection1|collection2)$/}}}]`

This is what the properties file looks like:

```
name=mongo-source
connector.class=com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSourceConnector
tasks.max=1

# Connection and source configuration
connection.uri=mongodb://mongo1:27017,mongo2:27017,mongo3:27017
database=test
collection=

topic.prefix=
poll.max.batch.size=1000
poll.await.time.ms=5000

# Change stream options
# pipeline=[{"$match":{"operationType":{"$in":["insert","update","replace","delete"]}}}]
pipeline=[{"$match": {"ns.coll": {"$regex": /^(collection1|collection2)$/}}}]

batch.size=0
publish.full.document.only=true
change.stream.full.document=updateLookup
collation=
```

I get the following message from running `bin/connect-standalone.sh`:

```
WARN Failed to resume change stream: {aggregate: 1} is not valid for '$changeStream'; a collection is required. 73
```

I'm using mongodb `v3.6`

Answer (score 0):

If you specify a `database` parameter, the connector expects that you will also supply a `collection` parameter.

In fact, if using Mongo 3.6 I believe you can only listen to a single database/collection combo at a time. This changed in Mongo 4.0, shown here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/4.0/#change-streams.